# Accessing the DOM of an Object that references another site

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am trying to access the DOM tree of a site I have in object form on my site.  Site below is fake.

```
<object id="site" type="text/html" data="www.TheSiteIWant.com" style="width:100%; height:100%"></object>
```

I then want to interact with its DOM structure.  There is a table (eventually several tables) that I want to pull data from.  Alternatively, if there is a way to just pull the table, that would be even better.  I have the ID and Class name, but trying the usual $("#tableName") doesn't seem to give me anything.  For instance, this will not work:

```
$("#tableName").hide()
```

won't change anything.  I'm guessing it might have to do with the type="text/html", but am unsure.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  I am doing this because I want to eventually use the table to make choices.  Essentially, the table ranks several things, from best to worst.  I want to take the user input, run it against the most up to date table data, and then give them their best choice.  I am also hoping to grab the names of the objects to be ranked, to populate the auto-complete list.  Hope that is more helpful.

Comment: You don't say why you are doing this, but are you sure you do not want an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)?

Comment: Added an edit with more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do (IIUC) is normally named "scraping" i.e. extracting and processing automatically data published from other web sites.

To do this there are specific libraries for many languages, but it's not something you can do in general from a web page in Javascript because of security reasons. What you can do from there is only accessing services that have been designed to be accessed that way because:

1. the provide a specific cross-site access permit
2. the information is published in json/xml

In that case using ajax requests is the normal way to access content from "other sites" (services on other servers).

Comment: I suppose that makes sense.  Just seems odd that I can display the whole website, but not have access to its elements.  I am doing this with c# MVC though, so would I be able to use a method through that to make further progress?

Comment: @Timotheus: you can **display** the site in another frame but you cannot access its content unless the page is from the same origin of your script. Even just this has been the source of some security threats (a malicious site could display a div that lets the click go through an opaque div to a button on an iframe that is hidden behind, thus it may let you click on a 1-click-buy button without you realizing it). I don't like this broken security model either (a resource that's available to everyone on the net except my script doesn't make sense) but is something web developers must live with.